# How to consume Web API OnInitialized in Blazor Child Component?

Tags: razor, components, httpclient, blazor, webassembly

I'm new to C# and Blazor WASM in general and have struggled with this for quite some time.

I have a parent component "Parent.razor" and child component "Child.razor"

In parents, apart from all other HTML stuff, I also have child tag. So it looks something like (just for example)

```
Parent.razor
@page "/machines"

<h1>Machine Information<h1>
<child></child>

@code
{
}
```

Now, there is a foreach loop in child component that iterate each item in a list (machinetypes)
If machinetypes is from a specified static list, it all works well.
[Screenshot for reference, I am able to get the dropdown that I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgoWt.png)

Code below.

```
Child.razor
@using Namespace.Shared.Models
@using Blazorise
@inject HttpClient Http


<select>
    @foreach (var machinetype in machinetypes)
    {
        <option value="@machinetype.MachineTypeId">@machinetype.MachineTypeName</option>
    }
</select>

@code {
    public int amachinetypeid { get; set; }

    //This works
    MachineType[] machinetypes = new MachineType[]
    {
        new MachineType{MachineTypeName="TypeX"},
        new MachineType{MachineTypeName="TypeY"}
    };
}
```

But when I try to consume web API (that also returns list), it doesn't work. The page loads indefinitely and I will encounter and error. Code below.

```
Child.razor
@using Namespace.Shared.Models
@using Blazorise
@inject HttpClient Http


<select>
    @foreach (var machinetype in machinetypes)
    {
        <option value="@machinetype.MachineTypeId">@machinetype.MachineTypeName</option>
    }
</select>

@code {
public int amachinetypeid { get; set; }
public MachineType[] machinetypes;

//This works
//MachineType[] machinetypes = new MachineType[]
//{
//   new MachineType{MachineTypeName="TypeX"},
//    new MachineType{MachineTypeName="TypeY"}
//};

//This does not work    
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    machinetypes = await Http.GetJsonAsync<MachineType[]>("api/machinetype/");
}

}
```

Quick check on my web API, accessing it directly returns this to me. So it works alright.
[Click here to see screenshot of web API results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZhMt.png)

Could anyone advise what I did wrong? And is necessary to create an dependency injection a necessity to do this? If yes, could anyone please point me to a right direction?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In addition to the answer, you may want to look at the OnParametersSetAsync "event" in case your data loading will depend on parameters coming from the parent. If you're on server-side Blazor, using OnInitialized will be hit twice (because of pre-rendering) so you may want to use OnAfterRenderAsync instead. Just tips for moving forward.

Comment: Hi @rdmptn. Thanks for the pointer. I think I face similar issue now. Now the parent and child components work,  but I can't render the parameter passed from parents to be default dropdown value.. I pass parameter from my parent called machinetypeid. When it comes to child component, I am able to get the list of machinetypes, but unable to set the default value even when I can successfully pass the parameter. code:  (<select value=@machinetypeid>) Does this have to do with the lifecycle "event" that you mentioned. What should be the correct one?

Comment: Onpatameterssetasync is the one. Pull days there and, if needed, call StateHasChanged

Comment: Alrighty. Thanks you once again! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably having a null-reference error. That might look like "loads indefinitely".

What you need is

```
public MachineType[] machinetypes = new MachineType[0];
```

Comment: Oh... stupid me. It works now. Thanks for pointing this out! :)